# Get input from user at command line and use that input to feed variables into Python script

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a script named `GetStats.py`.

At a high level, the `GetStats.py` script does the following:

1) makes a connection to an external database
2) retrieves some data from this database
3) writes the data retrieved in step 2 to a csv file

Importantly, the `GetStats.py` script references a configuration (.cfg) file, which includes (among many other details), the IP address and server details of the specific database to which to connect.

The `GetStats.py` script requires that the user pass the following parameters on the command line:

a) the number of days of data to retrieve (i.e. the look back period)
b) the granularity of the data (which is either hourly or daily)
c) whether to include a limited set of data (which takes about 30 minutes to run) or the full set of data (which takes about 1 hour and 15 minutes to run)

I also have a batch file that I use to run everything.  The batch file looks as follows:

```
GetStats.py Client_A.cfg 30 -d -full
GetStats.py Client_B.cfg 30 -d -full
GetStats.py Client_C.cfg 30 -d -full
GetStats.py Client_D.cfg 30 -d -full
GetStats.py Client_E.cfg 30 -d -full
... and so on up to Client_M
```

As we can see from the batch file above, the GetStats.py script is called and it runs against Client_A through Client_E for a period of 30 days, with daily granularity and returns the full set of data.

The problem is that if I want to change any of these parameters (e.g. change the number of days in the look back period, the data granularity and/or the set of data to return), I need to edit the batch file directly, and that process can take several minutes.

I'd like to streamline the process such that the user is prompted for the following **only once** at the command line once the batch file is run:

"Please enter the number of days to look back: "

"Please enter the granularity of the data: "

"Please enter the data set to return: "

I've given some thought as to how to incorporate these three parameters **directly** into the GetStats.py script.

But, I think I will run into a problem because the batch file will run the GetStats.py script and then prompt the user for the 3 parameters above **each time** the GetStats.py script is called (which is currently 13 times).

I don't want the user to have to enter "30", "-d" and "-full" a total of 13 times.  I'd like the user to enter "30", "-d" and "-full" **only once**.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can prompt the user for the above-mentioned 3 parameters **only once** after the batch file is run?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to do that in Python? It's a new process for every line in the batch file, so it doesn't make sense to try to share state across them. Take the input in the batch file. Or, if it's just you using it, use e.g. `awk` to quickly edit every line in the batch file.

Comment: No, it's not just me using it.  I'd rather have the user prompted to input the 3 parameters mentioned.  I don't understand what you're saying about "shared state" (I'm relatively new to Python and programming in general).

Answer (score 0):

Consider sourcing your *GetStats.py* as a module in a different .py script that receives user input via `input()` (or `raw_input()` in Python 2). In this way, you do no need a batch file or entering parameters via command line which is not a user-friendly interface. Plus, you can loop through all client types for a DRY-er approach using `string.ascii_uppercase`. Below is setup:

**GetStats.py**

*(wrap entire script in a defined module receiving the params previously sent via command line, no longer the `sys.argv[]` collection)*

```
def processData(clienttype, lookbackdaysparam, granularityparam, datasettypeparam):
   #...script...
```

**UserInput.py**

*(place in same directory as GetStats.py; consider controlling for numeric/string values)*

```
import GetStats
from string import ascii_uppercase

lookbackdays = ''; granularity = ''; datasettype = ''

# LOOP RUNS INFINITELY PROMPTING INPUT UNTIL USER FILLS OUT EACH ONE:
while True:    
    if lookbackdays == '':
        lookbackdays = input("Please enter the number of days to look back: ")

    elif granularity == '':
        granularity = input("Please enter the granularity of the data: ")

    elif datasettype == '':
        datasettype = input("Please enter the data set to return: ")

    else:
        break

# LOOPS THROUGH LETTERS A-M
for c in ascii_uppercase[0:13]:
    GetStats.processData('Client_'+c+'.cfg', lookbackdays, granularity, datasettype)

print("Successfully processed data!")
```

---

**Tkinter** GUI

Even better, consider an actual GUI interface using the [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html) module (pre-installed in Python 3):

```
import GetStats
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk 
from string import ascii_uppercase

class GUIapp():

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.buildControls()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def buildControls(self):        
        self.root.wm_title("Get Stats Menu")
        self.guiframe = Frame(self.root, width=2500, height=500, bd=1, relief=FLAT)
        self.guiframe.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

        # IMAGE
        self.photo = PhotoImage(file="Stats.png")
        self.imglbl = Label(self.guiframe, image=self.photo)
        self.imglbl.photo = self.photo
        self.imglbl.grid(row=0, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.imglbl = Label(self.guiframe, text="Enter parameters for data request",
                            font=("Arial", 12)).\
                            grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)

        # PERIOD DAYS 
        self.periodDayslbl = Label(self.guiframe, text="Please enter the number of days to look back: ",
                                  font=("Arial", 10)).grid(row=1, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.periodDaysvar = StringVar()
        self.periodDaystxt = Entry(self.guiframe, textvariable=self.periodDaysvar,
                                  relief=SOLID, font=("Arial", 10), width=34).\
                                  grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)

        # DATA GRANULARITY
        self.granularitylbl = Label(self.guiframe, text="Please enter the granularity of the data: ",
                                font=("Arial", 10)).grid(row=2, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.granularityvar = StringVar()
        self.granularitytxt = Entry(self.guiframe, textvariable=self.granularityvar,
                                relief=SOLID, font=("Arial", 10), width=34).\
                                grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)

        # DATASET TO RETURN
        self.datasetTypelbl = Label(self.guiframe, text="Please enter the data set to return: ",
                                font=("Arial", 10)).grid(row=3, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.datasetTypevar = StringVar()
        self.datasetTypetxt = Entry(self.guiframe, textvariable=self.datasetTypevar, relief=SOLID,
                                font=("Arial", 10), width=34).\
                                grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)

        # PROCESS BUTTON 
        self.btnoutput = Button(self.guiframe, text="PROCESS",
                                font=("Arial", 10), width=25, command=self.processData).\
                                grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W, padx=10, pady=5)

    def processData(self):
        if self.periodDaysvar.get() != '' and self.granularityvar.get() != '' and self.datasetTypevar.get() != '':    
            for c in ascii_uppercase[0:13]:
                GetStats.processData('Client_'+c+'cfg', self.periodDaysvar.get(), 
                                     self.granularityvar.get(), self.datasetTypevar.get())                   
                messagebox.showinfo("SUCCESFUL OUTPUT", "Successfully processed data!")
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("MISSING FIELD", "Please enter all fields to process request.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GUIapp()
```

**GUI** Menu *(image is a small pic named Stats.png in same directory as script)*

[image: GUI Menu]

Message Boxes *(called on Process button click)*

[image: GUI Success Message]
[image: GUI Error Message]